# setTimeout produces a scope error

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

My question is simple. I'm using setTimeout inside a for loop, during runtime
an error is produced saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

My experience with javascript is slim (I'm skipping jQuery for the sake of learning)
and I assume this has something with the way I'm calling setTimeout.

Take a look at my function, I would like to know why "elements" is not available from inside the anonymous function.

```
function hide_visable_elements()
{
    // remove body EventListener
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].removeEventListener("click", hide_visable_elements, true);

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
    {
    elements[i].removeAttribute("class");
    setTimeout(function() { elements[i].setAttribute("class", "hidden") }, 300);
    }   
}
```

Comment: The function you deferred executes long after the loop has completed, at that point `i === elements.length` and `elements[i]` is of course then `undefined` because it is out of bounds access.

Comment: How can I achieve the desired delay then? P.S according to what you're saying, if I change the 300ms to 0ms it should work, but its not.

Comment: before you defer a function, capture the value of `i` at that point so that when the function finally executes it will use the value you captured instead of whatever `i` is at that point. This has nothing to do with the amount of milliseconds, any amount makes it execute long after the loop has executed.

Comment: As I said, I'm quite new to all of this. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could capture the current value of the iteration so that when it is executed after the loop has completed (it *always* is *after*, because of the asynchronous nature), it will do the right thing:

```
function setHidden(element) {
    return function() {
        element.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
    };
}

function hide_visable_elements() {
    // remove body EventListener
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].removeEventListener("click", hide_visable_elements, true);
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        elements[i].removeAttribute("class");
        setTimeout(setHidden(elements[i]), 300);
    }
}
```

---

Btw I'm using the description "long after" relatively, the minimal amount of time that passes before your deferred functions could possibly be executed is 4 or 13 milliseconds but the loop execution time is measured in micro or nano seconds.

Comment: @elad.chen make sure you cleared the cache, here's working demo http://jsfiddle.net/7yWWz/1/

Comment: This is weird, I'm using the exact same code in the fiddle, and it doesn't work. Chrome is reporting the same errors as before. (Cache is cleared). Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Hard to say, did you ensure cache was cleared by clicking the error message line number and looking at the source code the error is shown in?

Comment: Yes, the error is produced in the very same line which has: "return function() { element.setAttribute("class", "hidden");};"

Comment: I guess then the only thing to do is to add console logs and follow the trail and see where it starts being undefined

Comment: Since the code I'm testing with only had one element with a class called "visible", the for loop only had one iteration. So I went and moved: "setTimeout(setHidden(elements[i]), 300);" one line up. which solved it. Thanks !

Comment: @elad.chen the code should work exactly the same regarless of the amount of iterations: 0, 1 or n.